# Problems free drawing on canvas after I add an image

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to use the camera to add an image to the canvas on an app that I have built using Phonegap and fabric.js.

This works, in so much as that it adds the image onto the screen. I have then managed to save it to the database and can re-display it after.

```
  function onPhotoURISuccessCanvas(imageURI){

  var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('cx0'); 
  canvas.setDimensions({width: 400, height: 600});

 fabric.Image.fromURL(imageURI, function(img) {
canvas.insertAt(img.set({ left: 400, top: 0, angle: 90, lockMovementX:true, lockMovementY: true,lockScaling: true, LockRotation:
true,selectable: false,isDrawingMode: true}).scale(0.25)),0; });


//this is the call to show the images
thisImage = serializeCanvasByIDx();

}

function serializeCanvasByIDx() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('cx0');
    var serializedVal = 'data:,';
    if (canvas.toDataURL) serializedVal = canvas.toDataURL(); 
    return serializedVal;
    }
```

I now want to be able to enable freedrawing so that I can sketch over the image

```
    function deviceReady() {

    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('cx0');
    canvas.setDimensions({width: 400, height: 600});
    var mode = document.getElementById('drawing-mode');

    mode.onclick = function() {
    canvas.isDrawingMode = !canvas.isDrawingMode;
    if (canvas.isDrawingMode) {
        mode.innerHTML = 'Enter edit mode';
    }
    else {
        mode.innerHTML = 'Enter draw mode';
    }


 };

    canvas.freeDrawingBrush = new fabric['PencilBrush'](canvas);
    canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = 'Black';
    canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = 4;

}
```

Drawing mode enables but as soon as i sketch, the image I added dissappears, I have tried quite a few different techniques, but can't see where I am going wrong.

All ideas appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Hi, was this ever figured out? Thanks!

Comment: I think I just loaded the image in a new page and it started to work, still took a bit of fiddling with though.